# Solr performance optimization

Tags: solr, lucene

I am working on a big website with pretty high traffic. I use Apache Solr as search engine. I have a lot of filters in my `qf`  param as you can see (which 'sections' to include search results from).

Will this kind of query affect performance noticably or is Solr optimized for this kind of query?

> http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx/solr/core1/select?q=%7b!frange+l%3d0.3%7dquery(%24qq)&qq=search+term&sort=publishdate+desc%2cscore+desc&hl.fl=*&hl.fragsize=240&hl.q=search+term&fq=contenttype%3a(default+OR+tv)&fq=publishdate%3a%5b*+TO+NOW%5d&fq=(publication%3publication-name+AND+home_section%3a(491+OR+492+OR+1872+OR+499+OR+500+OR+501+OR+503+OR+502+OR+514+OR+521+OR+511+OR+512+OR+508+OR+509+OR+510+OR+504+OR+518+OR+520+OR+519+OR+515+OR+517+OR+516+OR+505+OR+507+OR+506+OR+513+OR+522+OR+523+OR+524+OR+525+OR+526+OR+527+OR+528+OR+529+OR+530+OR+531+OR+532+OR+533+OR+534+OR+535+OR+536+OR+537+OR+538+OR+539+OR+541+OR+542+OR+543+OR+545+OR+544+OR+549+OR+551+OR+552+OR+550+OR+547+OR+563+OR+564+OR+565+OR+566+OR+567+OR+568+OR+569+OR+570+OR+571+OR+572+OR+573+OR+574+OR+1928+OR+575+OR+576+OR+1870+OR+577+OR+578+OR+579+OR+580+OR+581+OR+583+OR+582+OR+591+OR+592+OR+593+OR+584+OR+590+OR+585+OR+586+OR+587+OR+589+OR+588+OR+595+OR+596+OR+597+OR+599+OR+600+OR+601+OR+602+OR+603+OR+606+OR+607+OR+608+OR+609+OR+610+OR+604+OR+605+OR+611+OR+612+OR+613+OR+614+OR+615+OR+616+OR+617+OR+618+OR+619+OR+620+OR+621+OR+622+OR+598+OR+624+OR+626+OR+628+OR+630+OR+631+OR+625+OR+627+OR+1819+OR+629+OR+1820+OR+1951+OR+1952+OR+2647+OR+632+OR+1821+OR+2393+OR+2665+OR+1818+OR+633+OR+649+OR+2311+OR+2330+OR+1927+OR+651+OR+657+OR+1926+OR+654+OR+653+OR+652+OR+650+OR+493+OR+494+OR+497+OR+496+OR+495+OR+498+OR+1901+OR+638+OR+639+OR+886+OR+887+OR+888+OR+640+OR+641+OR+642+OR+643+OR+644+OR+645+OR+646+OR+647+OR+648+OR+658+OR+659+OR+660+OR+661+OR+662+OR+663+OR+664+OR+665+OR+666+OR+2764+OR+667+OR+668+OR+669+OR+670+OR+671+OR+672+OR+673+OR+674+OR+675+OR+881+OR+676+OR+677+OR+678+OR+679+OR+680+OR+681+OR+682+OR+683+OR+753+OR+754+OR+684+OR+685+OR+686+OR+687+OR+688+OR+689+OR+690+OR+691+OR+692+OR+693+OR+694+OR+695+OR+696+OR+697+OR+698+OR+699+OR+700+OR+701+OR+702+OR+703+OR+704+OR+705+OR+706+OR+707+OR+708+OR+709+OR+710+OR+711+OR+712+OR+713+OR+714+OR+715+OR+716+OR+717+OR+718+OR+719+OR+720+OR+721+OR+722+OR+723+OR+724+OR+725+OR+726+OR+727+OR+728+OR+729+OR+730+OR+731+OR+732+OR+733+OR+734+OR+735+OR+736+OR+737+OR+738+OR+739+OR+740+OR+741+OR+742+OR+743+OR+744+OR+745+OR+746+OR+768+OR+747+OR+748+OR+749+OR+750+OR+751+OR+752+OR+755+OR+756+OR+757+OR+758+OR+759+OR+760+OR+761+OR+762+OR+763+OR+764+OR+765+OR+766+OR+767+OR+2678+OR+769+OR+770+OR+847+OR+771+OR+772+OR+773+OR+774+OR+775+OR+783+OR+776+OR+777+OR+778+OR+779+OR+780+OR+781+OR+782+OR+784+OR+2420+OR+785+OR+786+OR+787+OR+788+OR+789+OR+790+OR+791+OR+792+OR+793+OR+794+OR+795+OR+796+OR+797+OR+798+OR+799+OR+800+OR+801+OR+802+OR+803+OR+804+OR+805+OR+806+OR+807+OR+882+OR+2682+OR+808+OR+809+OR+810+OR+811+OR+2765+OR+812+OR+813+OR+814+OR+815+OR+816+OR+817+OR+818+OR+819+OR+820+OR+821+OR+822+OR+823+OR+824+OR+825+OR+826+OR+827+OR+828+OR+829+OR+830+OR+832+OR+833+OR+834+OR+835+OR+836+OR+837+OR+838+OR+839+OR+840+OR+831+OR+841+OR+842+OR+843+OR+844+OR+845+OR+846+OR+848+OR+849+OR+850+OR+851+OR+852+OR+853+OR+854+OR+855+OR+856+OR+857+OR+858+OR+859+OR+860+OR+861+OR+862+OR+863+OR+864+OR+865+OR+866+OR+867+OR+868+OR+869+OR+870+OR+871+OR+872+OR+873+OR+874+OR+875+OR+876+OR+877+OR+878+OR+879+OR+880+OR+883+OR+884+OR+885+OR+1857+OR+634+OR+635+OR+1900+OR+1950+OR+889+OR+890+OR+891+OR+892+OR+893+OR+894+OR+895+OR+1747+OR+2350+OR+2106+OR+2072+OR+1755+OR+1752+OR+2060+OR+2061+OR+1756))+OR+(publication%3apublication2)&fq=-home_section%3a(2800+OR+2888+OR+2801+OR+2887+OR+2803+OR+2802+OR+2814+OR+2808+OR+2809+OR+2820+OR+2845+OR+2930)&&shards=xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx/solr/core2/,xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx/solr/core1/

Answer (score 2):

Solr uses Filter Caching mechanism to fetch the results quickly. You can find more info [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) regarding filters and caching.

Another challenge is with lengthy query is during the usage of GET, as it has a limit on servlet container. So you can switch to POST as a safe choice if you have not done already. Look [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/solr-select-query-get-vs-post) for some comparisons. 
If only GET, you can increase the limit. Look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#Enabling_Longer_Query_Requests)

And major part of your query is having home_section. Hope you have used range option rather than OR and end up with lengthy query. Of course your requirements should define it